# Why was contentEquals() method overloaded but not replaced?

Tags: java

I am reading *Effective Java* book right now and faced the following:

> Consider String, which has had a `contentEquals(StringBuffer)` method
>   since Java 4. In Java 5 String class was outfitted with an overloading
>   of the `contentEquals` method that takes a `CharSequence`.

Could you explain me why was the method overloaded if `contentEquals(StringBuffer)` can be replaced with `contentEquals(CharSequence)`?

Comment: But why? If the argument of the new one is more common so all instances of StringBuffer will be accepted. Am I wrong?

Comment: Binary compatibility. Removing the old method would have prevented old code using the method to run. The code would have had to be recompiled.

Comment: @JBNizet Somewhat surprising that it hasn't been deprecated and removed by now though. It's been 13 years.

Answer (score 3):

The change from `java.lang.String.contentEquals(StringBuffer)` to `java.lang.String.contentEquals(CharSequence)` wouldn't break the contract - even the implementation delegates to the newer overload: `return contentEquals((CharSequence)sb);`

The comments:

> ```
>  * @since  1.4
>  */
> public boolean contentEquals(StringBuffer sb) {
>
>  * @since  1.5
>  */
> public boolean contentEquals(CharSequence cs) {
> ```

suggest that the older method could have been simply replaced, because  `StringBuffer` implemented `CharSequence` [in version 1.4 already](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/), this `contentEquals(CharSequence)` overload having been added only in 1.5. 
But code compiled on Java v1.4 or older would fail to run on 1.5+ if `contentEquals(StringBuffer)` were just removed. 
So the only explanation left is *support for binaries produced on Java versions older than 1.5.*